# matplotlib installed but DLL load fails

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, dll

I'm having a problem running matplotlib on my machine. This identical code works on several other machines, all with the same python setup, so I'm at a loss as to what's happening. I have pip updated and matplotlib updated to their latest versions. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling matplotlib and other sub-functions. Python is also up to date (v3).

Whenever I import matplotlib in any code, python apparently checks versions (which is normal) but for me it crashes. I thought uninstalling/reinstalling would do it, but this message appears no matter what I try to do with matplotlib. Any advice? Desperate here!! I am not sure why a DLL load error would occur, I am only calling matplotlib to plot things.

```
  File "C:\PATH\code\decode_halo.py", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\PATH\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\PATH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 240, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Swidso3\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.'''
```

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: I am using the Anaconda distribution, that's what I have installed. 
I run python via the Windows cmd.exe prompt though. Perhaps the two aren't linked? How would I tell windows that when I type python in cmd.exe, to use the Anaconda distribution of python and not the Windows one?

Comment: Following up, when I run the python script in an Anaconda terminal it works fine! But when I run it in cmd.exe it doesn't work. Not sure how to manage paths...? Thanks

Comment: You need to use the anaconda prompt, not regular command prompt. The Anaconda prompt is just a regular command prompt with the path to load the Anaconda stuff

Comment: You can also type python at the Anaconda prompt. Regular cmd prompt commands work at the Anaconda prompt

Comment: Right, issue is my code has to use the cmd.exe to call python (it's part of an auto task schedule). I can't launch the anaconda prompt automatically, so I have to use cmd. Do you know how I can tell cmd to use the Anaconda distribution of python and environment, or some other solution?

Comment: Write a batch file that uses the same information that's in the Anaconda Prompt `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\...\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\...\anaconda3`

Comment: `call C:\Users\...\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat  C:\Users\...\anaconda3` calls and activates the anaconda batch script. `cd /d D:\users\...\Dropbox\PythonProjects` changes to a specific directory. `call jupyter lab` calls a command at the prompt. There are other question that address calling a specific file.

Comment: Hey thanks that worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following to resolve this error:

1. Reinstalled matplotlib -- this did **not** fix the error.
2. Downloaded two dll files msvcr71, msvcp71 -- this did **not** fix the error.
3. Downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable from Microsoft website URL:-https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145 -- this finally fixed the error